# Connecting to Oracle Database using 0xDBE

Tags: oracle, datagrip

I am trying to use 0xDBE and I am able to connect to the database with the host name and the database name but there are no tables populating. I checked the schemas & tables and the tables are not listed there either. I was thinking since there is an instance name that stays the same but there is also an Oracle alias that changes. There are two database, one for test and one for production. I am trying to connect to test. I can connect successfully to the instance name but I am not sure how to get to the Oracle instance and see my tables.

Actually, when I try to connect to the test database it gives me and error `Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor`

Comment: After reading through a few things I am found to guess that my client isn't allowed to connect to the database. Can anyone correct me on this or an I correct?

Comment: I had to do some weird stuff to get mine to finally connect. Could you post what your connect descriptor looks like as well as your TNSNames? Feel free to replace the actual names/addresses with generic ones.

Comment: Sorry about not updating the answer but it ended up being that my user credentials were not correct.

Comment: Great! Thank you for update